# Genymotion emulator shows black screen

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I installed genymotion emulator in c drive default location and from eclipse i also installed that plugin . i can run a emulator form virtual box or eclipse genymotion icon but emulator show only black screen and i cant run android project . Anyone can help me please , why happen this ? I also followed the FAQ section from genymotion site .

Comment: maybe checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547907/genymotion-stays-on-black-screen-when-loading-emulator/39547908#39547908

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that I had disabled GPU dynamic switching.  I have a program for Mac OS X called "gfxCardStatus", and I had it on the setting "Integrated Only" -- so it was only running on my integrated graphics card.  Switching back to the "Dynamic Switching" option fixed it for me, which allowed Genymotion to use the discrete card as well.

Comment: Worked for me. You need to make sure that you are using dynamic switching explicitly. Even using dedicated graphics directly does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with the GenyMotion emulator, but with emulators provided by Google they sometimes just show a black screen and no application.  This is usually fixed by selecting the Virtual device's Emulator option which tells the emulator to use the Host GPU.

On the Goggle AVD setup you find this by creating a new device or editing an existing one, and looking for the "Emulator Options" prompt.  Check the "Use Host GPU" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was disabling IPv6 (setting blank the IPv6 fields in the global settings / Network / host only / vboxnet1) the only thing that worked.

Answer (score -3):

You have to activate the camera. It's easily done by pressing Ctrl+3 (or by pressing the camera icon in the menu to the right) and switch from off to on. By default a dummy camera is selected for both front and back but you can replace them with a webcam by selecting it in the drop downs.